# How to display a list of files from a directory

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, filelist

My task is to display a list of files in a given directory. Below is my existing code:

```cpp
FileListBox1->FileEdit = Edit1;
FilterComboBox1->FileList = FileListBox1;
DirectoryListBox1->FileList = FileListBox1;
DirectoryListBox1->DirLabel = Label1;
DriveComboBox1->DirList = DirectoryListBox1;
Button1->Default = true;
```

So far, everything works fine, but I only have `*.txt` files in the directory and I want to skip this type of feed and immediately narrow the file extension to `*.txt`.

I've already tried something like this:

```
String fileType = L"*.txt";
FileListBox1->FileEdit = fileType;
```

And some other solutions, but every time I get an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an error because you are trying to assign a `String` where a `TEdit*` is expected.

If you want the `TFileListBox` to display a particular type(s) of file programmably, get rid of the `TFilterComboBox` and use the [`TFileListBox::Mask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TFileListBox.Mask) property instead:

> Limits which files are displayed in the file list box.
>
> Set Mask to a regular expression to limit the list box to files that match the mask. The value of the mask is a file name that may include wildcards.

```
String fileType = _D("*.txt");
FileListBox1->Mask = fileType;
```

That said, the file UI components you are using are *ancient*, they were designed during the Windows 3.1 era and should not be using in modern software.

Look at the RTL's [`FindFirst()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) and [`FindNext()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindNext) functions to programmably enumerate files with mask filtering. See [Finding a File](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Finding_a_File) in Embarcadero's documentation for more details.